# Client End Point Address In WCF web.config

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, soap, wcf-endpoint

I am new to web service have a doubt regarding setting of `<client>` endpoint in      the `web.config` of `Accounts.svc.`
    Please check the picture attached where i have explained my architecture.

```
Server Setting in iis service name:https://prddb02:448/Accounts.svc and 
external wsdl :https://company.****/*****?SOAP
   (authenticated with username,password & proxy)
```

```xml
 <client>
    <endpoint address="https://company.****/*****?SOAP"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="CodeItSoap"
    contract="Service.CodeItSoap" name="CodeItSoap" />
 </client>
```

OR

```xml
<client>
     <endpoint address="https://prddb02:448/Accounts.svc"
     binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="CodeItSoap"
     contract="Service.CodeItSoap" name="CodeItSoap" />
</client>
```

Which end point address to use.
Please help me getting this clear.
[image: Architecture diagram]

Comment: The second one is correct. Are you getting an error?

Comment: Could you tell me the reason why should i set the second one??

Comment: i can access the url from browser but when i am running the application and calling a required function i am not getting response from the service.

Comment: Could you post the code you're using from the client? Did you add the service reference in your client project? It could be anything really. Did you try accessing the web service URL from the server your application is on or your dev. machine?

Comment: I am using the httpwebrequest .getresponse to hit the server and  it returns no value to the response.Client project in the sense you are talking about the application project or the web service project where i am creating Accounts.svc??

Comment: i ran the web service url in my machine and its running saying service has been created with the wsdl file.

Comment: I would suggest reading this: http://www.csharptutorial.in/36/csharp-net-how-to-create-a-wcf-service-in-visual-studio-2010-using-csharp-net At the bottom of that article there is a link for 'consuming' a web service. I'm assuming you're using .NET to for the client as well.

Comment: why i am having confusion with the client end point is because when i set the client endpoint address as first one in error log i get error "no endpoint listening at here was no endpoint listening at https://company.****/*****?SOAP that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.. that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details."

Comment: when i set the https://prddb02:448/Accounts.svc as end point i get error cannot connect due to ssl/tls connection refused.